# Wordpress Error log growing by GB's in a few hours

Tags: wordpress, error-log

The error log on my site has just suddenly started filling up in just a few hours. Just this afternoon I came to it and found a 3.5GB file and that is after clearing it earlier in the day.

It seems that someone or something is trying to access images but the directory is very strange and looks something like this:

/home/sitename/public_html/wp-content/uploads/images/image.jpg/feed

The file is full of these with /feed and the odd few ending in error_log

Any ideas of how I can block these or solve the problem?

Comment: Can you post some more detailed information? The full lines of the log

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on a similar event which happened at my previous company:
It seems with Wordpress that this is a kind of 'hack'/attack where attempts are made to add images to your site which would contain harmful elements, with the intent that activity/traffic through your site would spread whatever it is.

In our case we were informed of this when our host closed down the Wordpress site and sent us an email indicating the new images as suspicious and probably dangerous.

How we managed to block it was to change access details for admins or users with the ability to add/create content and because it was on a Linux server we wangled the writing permissions of the location the images were saved in.

Comment: It could be this but the images which are being looked for do exist if you remove the /feed from the URL.

Comment: Interesting. It could be that they misinterpreted the location of the images in your setup/theme? But alas,such a speculation would not help much to answer your question.

Comment: Strange, just as fast as it started it has stopped.